# How to make PayPal Agreement start_date valid in PayPal SDK for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

As PayPal [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/#billing-agreements_create) says:

> ...start date must be no less than 24 hours after the current date...

Furthermore, judging by [PayPal Source code repository](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/BillingAgreementCreateAndExecute.aspx.cs) start_should looks like `"2016-02-19T00:37:04Z"`

What is I did is:

```
var agreement = new Agreement() {
    name = Plan.name,
    description = $"Agreement for {Plan.description}",
    start_date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(25).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ"),
    payer = payer,
    plan = new Plan() { id = Plan.id },
};

agreement.Create(myAPIContext);
```

And here is the result. My `start_date` seems right.
[image]

But after that I immediately catch an Exception:
[image]

So, what's the problem?

Comment: as per this line https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/BillingAgreementCreateAndExecute.aspx.cs#L99 , you may need to use this format `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" ` . Can you try with this `DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(25).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");`

Comment: @Niladri, yes, you're absolutely right! Can't believe I've missed that up! That comment should be an answer.

Comment: ok posting it as answer .. Can you accept it ?

Comment: @Niladri, of course!

Comment: I have posted it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Paypal [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/#billing-agreements_create) the `start_date` parameter accepts string formatted ISO 8601 datetime. In this case it is of format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`(as per the sample code) . Hence your code should be like this

```
var agreement = new Agreement() {
    name = Plan.name,
    description = $"Agreement for {Plan.description}",
    start_date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(25).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"),
    payer = payer,
    plan = new Plan() { id = Plan.id },
};

agreement.Create(myAPIContext);
```